# How can I pack two int16 into a single byte32?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.5.x

I have a contract that makes use of cartesian coordinates. My initial thought is to map a single location (x,y) to a value/struct. I would like to define any given pair of coordinates by a single `byte32` that can be converted back into coordinates. Ex:

```
int16 x, int16 y;
byte32 key = coordinatesToBytes32(x, y);
```

and vise-versa:

```
[x, y] = bytes32ToCoordinates(key);
```

After jumping into `solc@^0.5.0` I discovered you can no longer explicitly  convert between these types which made it difficult for me to cast, mask, shift, and run bitwise operations. For reference, here is where I made it to (note the solidity version):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CoordinateUtils {
    function coordinatesToBytes32(int16 x, int16 y) internal pure returns(bytes32) {
        return (bytes32(x) << 16 & 0xFFFFFFFF) | bytes16(y);  // left shift extends negative so we mask out
    }
    function bytes32ToCoordinates(bytes32 b) internal pure returns(int16 x, int16 y) {
        return (int16(b >> 16), int16(b));
    }
}
```

Also, I am open to other suggestions on the storage of cartesian related values if this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `int16` is just 2 bytes wide (16 bit), not 16 bytes.  Did you mean `int128`?

Second, you still may pack/unpack two `int16` values into single `bytes32` in Solidity 0.5.x, you just need a bit more type casts:

```
function pack (int16 a, int16 b) public pure returns (bytes32) {
  return bytes32 (bytes2 (a)) >> 16 | bytes2 (b);
}

function unpack (bytes32 x) public pure returns (int16, int16) {
  return (int16 (bytes2 (x << 16)), int16 (bytes2 (x)));
}
```

Note, the direction of shifts.  This is because, for `bytesN` widening works differently than for numbers:

```
bytes2 a = 0x0102;
bytes4 b = bytes32 (a); // 0x01020000 (padded from right)

int16 c = 0x0102;
int32 d = int32 (c); // 0x00000102 (padded from left)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for correcting me on the `int16` byte length. So in this scenario it would make more sense to pack two `int128` into a `bytes32`, or two `int16` into a `bytes4` correct? Also good to know about the different padding behaviors, I can see why they made this change that @markus-waas pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior changed in Solidity 0.5.x.

> Conversions between bytesX and uintY of different size are now
>   disallowed due to bytesX padding on the right and uintY padding on the
>   left which may cause unexpected conversion results. The size must now
>   be adjusted within the type before the conversion. For example, you
>   can convert a bytes4 (4 bytes) to a uint64 (8 bytes) by first
>   converting the bytes4 variable to bytes8 and then to uint64. You get
>   the opposite padding when converting through uint32.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html

So you can convert an int16 to bytes32 like this:

```
int16 x = 5;
bytes32 y = bytes32(int256(x));
```

Ensure that this is your intended behavior according to the padding ('bytesX padding on the right and uintY padding on the left').